# Editing .txt file Java

Tags: java, input

I need to to write a Java program that will write entered information in the console to a .txt file. If the .txt file already exists it will have to open it and write the additional information on another line. If the .txt file doesn't exist for a new "Lifter" it will create the .txt and write it in. Basically I don't know how to create a new .txt for each name entered and how to edit it if the person's .txt already exists. How would I go about doing that?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MeetPrinter {

    public static void getInfo() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int question;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int squat;
        int bench;
        int lift;
        String meetName;
        do {

            System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
            firstName = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
            lastName = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Enter new Meet Name: ");
            meetName = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Enter max squat weight in kg: ");
            squat = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter max bench press in kg: ");
            bench = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter max deadlift in kg: ");
            lift = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out
                    .println("Enter '1' to enter more lifters or '2' if you are done entering.");
            question = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (question == 1);

        try{
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100000);
            out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName + " Record #: " + randomInt);
            out.println("");
            String meet = "Meet Name";
            String sq = "SQ Max";
            String bp = "BP Max";
            String sub = "SUB Total";
            String dl = "DL Max";
            String tot = "Total";
            out.printf("%20s %15s %18s %19s %18s %18s",meet ,sq,bp,sub,dl,tot);
            out.println("");
            out.printf("%20s", meetName);
            out.printf("%10d (%6.2f)", squat, squat * 2.2);
            out.printf("%10d (%6.2f)", bench, bench * 2.2);
            float subPounds = (float) ((float)(squat + bench) * 2.2);
            out.printf("%10d (%6.2f)", squat + bench, subPounds);
            out.printf("%10d (%6.2f)", lift, lift * 2.2);
            float tPounds = (float) ((float)(squat + bench + lift) * 2.2);
            out.printf("%10d (%6.2f)", squat + bench + lift, tPounds);
            out.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

change

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
```

to

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter("output.txt", true);
```

The `true` will tell the FileWriter to append to the file if it exists, which is exactly what you want to do.

here is the javadoc for [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

The FileWriter has the option to write Strings, which is what you do.

Also like twain249 suggested, do something about the path...

Comment: Also you should change the `"output.txt"` to a full (or relative) file path because this will look for a file named "output.txt" in the directory that you run the code from (usually a `/bin`).

Comment: you havnt answered what he must do to create a new file if it does not exist

Comment: @EnKrypt the FileOutputStream will do that automatically.

Comment: Oh I was not aware of that. This is why i love SO , you get to learn somehting everyday.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. When I changed it to FileOutputStream, all my printf(s) and println(s) became underlined in red. Sorry I am a novice in Java. Also, the file names of the .txt has to be the name of the "Lifters". How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JohnSmith read the page in the link I gave you, you'll need to use the proper methods of the FileOutPutstream in Java. If you're really that new, I'd say that's a complex program to write for your skill level.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Yes, I am taking a Java class right now and the instructor basically just hand out the homework and doesn't teach much in class. He basically is forcing us to do the projects and homework using the self-taught method. Most of the code you see that I posted is basically written with the help of Google.

Comment: @JohnSmith the self-teaching method is good as long as you have basic knowledge to start with. If you don't, there's absolutely no point to the class you're taking.

Answer (score 1):

**Java File operation**

```
File file  = new File("<file name>");
BufferedWriter writer = null;

if(file.exists()){ //Check existence check 
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(toFile,true)); 
//bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning
}else{
file.createNewFile() //creating new file
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(toFile)); 
}
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(writer);
writer.write(...);
---or----
PrintWriter out
   = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(writer));
out.println(...);
```